# Vim styling editing

Tags: indentation, gnome-terminal, neovim, vim-airline, powerline

so I just switched to neovim and I need some help because I am not fimiliar with the new envoriment I'm having, which are 2 major ones. And please keep in mind that when I am refering to neovim it is the same thing as refering to vim.

**Neovim customization**
I would like to know that how can I remove or add items through status bar...I find some items such as the file extension pretty unnecessary and I 
would like to remove it. And also I am having problems rendering the unix icons as you can see in [this](http://ibb.co/juO137) picture.

**Dot Indenting**
I would also like to know how to edit my configuration file in such way that instead of displaying empty space in the indenting lines I can display dots as you can see in [this](https://ibb.co/hyBqVn) picture.

If you would like to have additinol information you can find my neovim configuration file [here](http://textuploader.com/dxrzx) and some system information [here](http://textuploader.com/dxrzu).
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show spaces by dots using this commands

`:set list`

`:set listchars+=space:.`

Or you can replace `.` with any other character you like.